# How designed my android application ? (GMap api, AsyncTask)

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I need advices for design my android application, it's my first App so I'm not very sure of my conception.

Source code available here:
https://code.google.com/p/android-express-project/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fandroid-express-project

**I have to:**
Create an app who ask to connect the user first, after the app must get the round of my deliverer (user connected) for display all his delivery as waypoint on a google map.
The app must display the most speed way for deliver all clients. The start and the end points are the same generally. When the deliverer is near of a delivery point, I need to detect this and auto call another Activity who display a scanner for the packets to deliver.

**What I have already done:**
I have an Activity (**NextDelivery**) who extends to RoboActivity (API who uses annotations like @Inject for bind values into View, etc. Not really different than usual Activity class).
This activity has two intern private classes:

- **FollowMeLocationSource** who implements LocationSource and LocationListener. Useful for detect the user's location and add marker to the map.
- **RoundXmlTask** who extends to AsyncTask. Useful for get a XML file who contains all my deliveries, senders, receivers, packets. This file is very important because without it's I can know where the deliverer must go. So I need to get the file, parse, and store the datas into my db. (This part works correctly) But it's slow so I wanted to do this into a AsynchTask for don't block my ThreadUI. Once the parse is done, I get my data from the DB, not from the XML but it's take time too, less but I won't do it on the ThreadUI.

Actually my steps are:

1. Launch NextDelivery.onCreate
2. Get instance of followMeLocationSource, init the map and execute the asyncTask.

Direct link: https://code.google.com/p/android-express-project/source/browse/trunk/android-express-project/src/com/app/express/activity/NextDelivery.java

But if I do like that, I have two asyncTask launched (Because, on followMeLocationSource.onLocationChanged() I launch my RoundTask who call the Google webservice direction for get the points, their ordrer and draw the road on the map)

It's works but I think I can do very better.
(And it don't works perfectly, many Toast are displayed and the road of steps is not draw the first time)

So, I would know how is the best practice for do that better.
Thank you for your time and your help.

PS: You can download the source code from the SVN and test if you want, you need add google_play_service_lib to the projet, it's all.

Comment: You can connect to the app with the login leo@gmail.com. Psw: leo for example. It's manage locally, no call to an extern server.

Comment: Nobody could advise me ?